# Duplicate symbol function in C++

Tags: c++, xcode

I have the below `main()` function call in Hello.cpp

```
#include "HelloWorld.cpp"

int main(){
HelloWorld helloWorld;
helloWorld.printHelloWorld();
return 0;
}
```

The other c++ , file which is included has the below code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class HelloWorld{
        public:
        void printHelloWorld();
};

void HelloWorld::printHelloWorld() {
    std::cout << "This is the world" << std::endl;
}
```

When I execute with Xcode , I see duplicate symbols for `printHelloWorld`.

```
duplicate symbol 'HelloWorld::printHelloWorld()' in: Hello.o HelloWorld.o

ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
```

How can I fix the above issue?

Comment: You are compiling `HelloWord.cpp` twice; once when `#include`ing it, the other when you compile it. You can only do one.

Comment: You should not be `#include`ing .cpp files. Put the class definition in a header, and include that in both your source files. ([Books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) usually mention how to structure things.)

Comment: Header files are were you can put declarations that can be used by multiple translation units.  Source files are where definitions go.  C++ itself doesn't make any distinction between the two, that's just a C Preprocessor facility that developers use to organize their code and not repeat themselves, which is why `#include "HelloWorld.cpp"` isn't detected as an error at compile time.

Comment: @cigien thanks for pointing that compilation issue, I am trying to understand how will the compilation work if I include the declaration in a different file as mentioned by others versus the one I have mentioned in the my question. If any one can throw some light on it , that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your file structure wrong.

Non-defining declarations belong in a header file (`.h` or `.hpp` ending by convention):

```
// HelloWorld.h

// No standard library headers required, because you don't use anything from `std::`

class HelloWorld{
    public:
    void printHelloWorld();
};
```

(Non-inline) definitions belong in a source file (`.cpp` or `.cxx` or `.cc` by convention):

```
// HelloWorld.cpp

#include "HelloWorld.h"

#include <iostream>
// #include<string> is not needed, since you don't use `std::string` here

void HelloWorld::printHelloWorld() {
    std::cout << "This is the world" << std::endl;
}
```

and source files should not be included in other files. Only the header files with the declarations should be included:

```
#include "HelloWorld.h"

int main(){
    HelloWorld helloWorld;
    helloWorld.printHelloWorld();
    return 0;
}
```

Each source file is by convention compiled as individual translation unit and there may be a definition for a (non-inline) function in only *one* of the translation units.

`#include` does essentially nothing more than copy-paste the code from the other file into the files using it. So if you include the `.cpp` with a definition in another `.cpp` file, then both translation units for the two `.cpp` files will contain the definition, violating the one-definition-rule mentioned above.

Your error is telling you that you have the definition for `HelloWorld::printHelloWorld()` (which is not inline) in two translation units.